# Select records with fewer than 10 entries sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want only to display the The ID which have record less than 10 entries for each ID,  an ID may have several values as you see in the data below. i want 
i have tried this query but it selects also the record for ID 2

```
   select ID, Name ,LastName ,PaymentDate,POSITION
    From ( select ID, Name ,LastName ,PaymentDate    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PaymentDate DESC) AS POSITION 

     )
     where Position < 10
```

any help please

```
 ID   Name LastName PaymentDate
  1    John Abraham  2015-05-08
  1    John Abraham  2014-05-08 
  1    John Abraham  2013-05-08
  1    John Abraham  2012-05-08
  1    John Abraham  2011-05-08
  1    John Abraham  2010-05-08
  ------------------------------
  2    Adam White    2015-05-08
  2    Adam White    2014-05-08 
  2    Adam White    2013-05-08
  2    Adam White    2012-05-08
  2    Adam White    2011-05-08
  2    Adam White    2010-05-08
  2    Adam White    2009-05-08
  2    Adam White    2008-05-08 
  2    Adam White    2007-05-08
  2    Adam White    2006-05-08
  2    Adam White    2005-05-08
  2    Adam White    20004-05-08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
Select ID, Name, LastName, PaymentDate
  From MyTable
 Where ID in (Select ID From MyTable Group By ID Having Count(*) < 10);
```

Comment: thanks a lot , this works very well as expected. i have done like this query , there was a bit error in the sub-query .

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(ID)
FROM sometable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) < 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `count(*)`, not `row_number()`:

```
select ID, Name, LastName, PaymentDate
from (select ID, Name, LastName, PaymentDate,
             count(*) over (partition by ID) as cnt 
      from . . .
     ) t
where cnt < 10;
```

This displays the rows (which your question suggests is what you want).  If you want only the ids, then aggregation is better:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(*) < 10;
```

Comment: thanks Gordon but it does not work , it really works in sub-query as below.

Comment: @Ilyas . . . What do you mean "it does not work"?  These should be doing what you are asking for.

Comment: I have tried your query , but it does not give me the expected result . the query display also some ID which have more 10 entries

Comment: @Ilyas . . . It is not possible for either query to do that.